# WPF Resource Dictionary XSLT

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, resourcedictionary

To use images in wpf you can define:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <BitmapImage x:Key="ImageFunTime"
                 UriSource="../Resources/Images/ImageFunTime.png" />
</
```

Then in app somewhere you can:

```
var img = (ImageSource)positionsTab.TryFindResource("ImageFunTime");
```

How can I achieve the same thing with an embedded Xslt file? That is, whats the syntax in the resource dictionary, as its obviously not an Bitmap image...

TIA

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve the same thing with
>   an embedded Xslt file?

**Answers**:

1. None of the Microsoft's XSLT processor supports embedded XSLT stylesheets. You will need a complete, XSLT-only file for your XSLT stylesheet.
2. In XSLT one uses the [**`<xsl:key>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key) instruction and the [**`key()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-key) function for efficient selecting nodes by some string value, that identifies them uniquely.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="UriSourceByKey"
  match="@UriSource" use="../@x:Key"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vImageFunTime"
  select="key('UriSourceByKey', 'ImageFunTime')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="$vImageFunTime"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <BitmapImage x:Key="ImageFunTime"  UriSource="../Resources/Images/ImageFunTime.png" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
../Resources/Images/ImageFunTime.png
```

Comment: I think that the OP wants to declare a XSLT stylesheet as a resource (like the image in question) and then to retrive it into the C# application.

Comment: @Alejandro: Then, if he is asking about what the type of the resource should be, the answer is: string.